# React container props child passing

Tags: reactjs

afraid that question is simple stupid but im stuck(

I have a Box component with some nested ones:

```
<Box.Content anyProp="prop">
  <Box.Text...
  <Box.Links
```

How I can pass ALL the props form Box.Content to ALL child containers (Box.Text, Box.Links, anything else)?

Trying with no luck:

```
BoxComponent.Content = (...props) => (
  <BoxContent {...props}>{props.children}</BoxContent>
);
```

Then trying to catch any prop from Parent inside child container - no props listed(

Comment: To clarify, in your example you want `anyProp="prop"` to be applied to `Box.Text` and `Box.Links`?

Comment: yes, its correct, if it could be when I write   <Box.Tex anyProp=...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to dynamically set a parent's props on its children.

Run the following code snippet. `prop1` and `prop2` on the `Parent` component are passed to the `Child1` and `Child2` components.

```js
const Child1 = (props) => <p>Child 1: {JSON.stringify(props)}</p>;
const Child2 = (props) => <p>Child 2: {JSON.stringify(props)}</p>;

const Parent = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  children = children.map(v => React.cloneElement(v, props));

  return <div id="parent">{children}</div>;
};

const App = () => (
  <Parent prop1="foo" prop2="bar">
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
  </Parent>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you! in case I need not all the prop but one PropName? May be its more simple solution?

Comment: To specify a certain prop you would just need to use `React.cloneElement(v, props.propName)`.